# Genere dei nomi composti verbo+sostantivo

Tags: grammar, gender

Esiste una regola specifica per dire se un nome composto della forma “verbo+sostantivo” è maschile o femminile? All'inizio pensavo che fosse sempre maschile (il tergicristallo, il reggilibri, lo stendibiancheria, il calzascarpe), ma poi mi è venuto in mente che dico **la** lavastoviglie.

Voi che ne pensate?

Answer (score 2):

La mia ipotesi è che tutto dipenda dal fatto che inconsciamente io penso a una **macchina** per lavare le stoviglie e uno **strumento** / **oggetto**  per stendere la biancheria, ma ammetto che è una teoria poco fondata...

Answer (score 1):

[Qui](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/genere-dei-nomi_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/) trovi le regole riguardanti il genere dei sostantivi elencate nella Treccani; non ne ho lette riguardanti i nomi composti, quindi suppongo che rimanga "una convenzione esclusivamente linguistica ", come scritto nella sopra citata enciclopedia.

Comment: Che il genere dei nomi degli oggetti inanimati sia arbitrario immagino che l'OP lo sapesse già: la domanda è molto più specifica...

Comment: La domanda è "Esiste una regola specifica[...]?" Nella mia risposta vi è il collegamento alla pagina con le regole riguardanti il genere dei sostantivi, dato che non c'è una regola come quella richiesta, la risposta implicita è "No, non esiste una regola specifica."